# Calling JSON array using variable

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

My problem is that I want to use my argument in the `getSummoner` function and apply it to my JSON print message query - `profile.summonerName.name`.

```
const https = require('https');

function printMessage(username, level) {
  const message = `${username} is summoner level ${level}`;
  console.log(message);
}

function getSummoner(summonerName){
        const request = https.get('https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/${summonerName}?api_key={myAPI}', response => {
            let body = "";
            response.on('data', data => {
                body += data.toString();
            });


            response.on('end', () => {
                const profile = JSON.parse(body);
                printMessage(profile.cygnuscrossna.name, profile.cygnuscrossna.summonerLevel)
                console.log(profile)

            });

        });
}

getSummoner("cygnuscrossna")
```

`console.log` will spit out this JSON:

```
{
    cygnuscrossna:{
       id: 58971790,
       name: 'CygnusCrossNA',
       profileIconId: 1301,
       revisionDate: 1474365186000,
       summonerLevel: 15
    }
}
```

and print message spits out:

> CygnusCrossNA is summoner level 15

But it spits out correctly because I did: 
`profile.cygnuscrossna.name`, `profile.cygnuscross.summonerLevel`

How can I exchange these with my argument `summonerName`?

Comment: Thanks you @melpomene